# What distribution does this data take?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, bimodal

I have several unique ID's that have this distribution, but I cannot find any information on the type. I'm leaning on this being a bimodal distribution, but am not sure. I need to fit these to a theoretical model to extract important parameters.

If there is not a popularized function for this distribution, can anyone recommend a python library (like `scipy.optimize`) that can help give me parameters for this type of model? Any input would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please explain what these "important parameters" might represent.

Comment: It almost looks like some kind of shifted and (slightly) stretched beta distribution, but whuber is right that more context will be helpful. For instance, do you want to sample from that distribution?

Comment: Indeed, @Dave looks like a beta distribution with offset and possibly stretched $x$-axis range, but we do need more information. Sure, one can use a FindDistribution routine, e.g., in Mathematica, but one does not have any confidence in a distribution type without considering the nitty-gritty generative process that led to the data, and that requires some theoretical work, not just educated guesswork.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback